# How to render an html entity in React.js without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    {"type": "button", "className": "close"},
    "&times;"),
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Prints '& times;' instead of ×

I was able to fix it by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but as the name states, I don't think *dangerously* is the best possible solution

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    {"type": "button", "className": "close", "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" : {__html: "&times;"}},
    null),
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can find the last snippet here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pzb3ygxj/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use an escaped unicode code point:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    {"type": "button", "className": "close"},
    "\u00D7"),
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can even just use the literal character:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(
    "button",
    {"type": "button", "className": "close"},
    "×"),
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The HTML entity, in a string, is escaped by React.

There's some documentation here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals

Comment: What about for entities that we don't know ahead of time. For instance here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48471323/1828637