# Array of html entities "&#xf101;" how to print? as unicode (not working)?

Tags: reactjs, unicode

I have an array of HTML entities (custom font) that looks like this:

```
const arr = ['&#xf101;'];
```

Now when I print it out like this:

```
render() {
   return (
      <div className="ff">
          { arr[0] }
      </div>
   )
}
```

It prints the string. I am trying to convert it to unicode like this:

```
{ arr[0].replace('&#', '\\u') }
```

But then this just prints the string "\uxf100".

I was having to do this to get it to work:

```
{ React.createElement('span', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML:{ __html:arr[0] }}, null) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(arr[0].replace(/&#x|;/g,''),16))
//
```

Try this first we replace `'&#x'` and `';'` with `''`, then with `parseInt()` we convert it from hexadecimal to decimal, then with `String.fromCodePoint()` we convert the decimal code point into a Javascript string.

Comment: This works thanks Steven! However I had to remove the ` - 1`.

Comment: Ah that's interesting, perhaps the codepoint identifier site misidentified the code point. I'll edit the question.