# Weird unicode symbols, cannot parseInt, getting NaN

Tags: javascript, unicode

Similar to this topic here - [Array of html entities "&#xf101;" how to print? as unicode (not working)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48471323/1828637)

I have an array of HTML entities (custom font) that looks like this:

```
const arr = ['crop_&#x31;&#x36;_&#x39;', 'computer', '&#x33;d_rotation', '&#xf100;'];
```

The only one I am able to succefsully print is `&#xf100;` by doing:

```
render() {
    return <span> String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(arr[0].replace(/&#x|;/g,''),16)) </span>
}
```

However the others throw errors like this:

parseInt is NaN
SOME_NUMBER_HERE is out of range for String.fromCodePoint

Is there anyway to String.fromCodePoint and parseInt this?

Comment: Please post the exact input, the desired output, your attempts at a solution and a clear description of your issue with your code.

Comment: Updated it @Bergi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the proper solution would be not to generate JS string literals with HTML entities in them - JS does support unicode directly - but if you insist here's how to do it.

Your current attempt seems to work only when the whole string is a single entity, using `replace` to remove the non-integer parts and then get a single character code. This obviously cannot work if the string contains normal characters and multiple entities. In that case, you need to replace each entity by its unicode character *in* the string:

```
arr[0].replace(/&#x([0-9a-f]+);/gi, (_, code) => String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(code, 16)))
```

Comment: Oooooh, duhh shoot. I didn't realize that a string can be a unicode. Sheesh. Thanks!!!!